# Why this Hive QL should be grouped by 'ds'?

Tags: hive, hiveql

```
select 
(floor(cast(ds as bigint)/100)) as date_time,
count(DISTINCT trans_id) as n_trans
from xxx
where ds >= "20140301" and adzone_id = '10263209'
group by 1;
```

---

```
Begin execute SQL: select 
(floor(cast(ds as bigint)/100)) as date_time,
count(DISTINCT trans_id) as n_trans
from xxx
where ds >= "20140301" and adzone_id = '10263209'
group by 1
Hive history file=/xxx.txt
FAILED: Error in semantic analysis: Line 0:-1 Expression not in GROUP BY key 'ds'
over
```

ds = `yyyyMMdd` and date_time is `yyyymm`(ds div 100 and floor).

I just groupby field `1(date_time)`, but why the compile say it should be grouped by 'ds'?

edit:

`ds` is the field for partition.

Answer (score 0):

Hive group by can be done on raw column data